# Search database for string of text, possibly tags

Tags: mysql, string, search, tags, full-text-search

This is somewhat of an open question, however my main reason for asking is to either know the 'name' of such a task, or to be pointed in the right direction of what I should be looking for.

What I am trying to achieve is a database of items which can be *tagged*. The format to which will be strings of text.

For example, if we are talking about Movies.

```
table_movies
  movie_id
  movie_title
  movie_genre

table_tags
  tag_id
  movie_id
  tag_text
```

The Movie will only be entered into its respective table once. In the `table_tags` table, the `movie_id` can be listed an unlimited amount of times, one for each *tag*.

```
table_movies
  movie_id    movie_title      movie_genre
  1           Notting Hill     Romantic Comedy
  2           Jurassic Park    Science Fiction, Action Adventure
  3           Grease           Musical
  4           Salt             Action Adventure
  5           Gladiator        Drama, Epic, Historical, Adventure, Action
  6           E.T.             Science Fiction, Action Adventure, Fantasy

table_tags
  tag_id      movie_id      tag_text
  1           1             Notting
  2           1             Hill
  3           1             London
  4           1             Market
  5           2             Jurassic
  6           2             Park
  7           2             90s
  8           2             T-Rex
  9           2             Amber
  10          2             Egg
  11          3             Grease
  12          3             Cars
  13          3             Diner
  14          4             Salt
  15          4             Undercover
  16          4             Twist
  17          4             Agent
  18          5             Gladiator
  19          5             Shield
  20          5             Roman
  21          1             Boy gets girl
  22          3             Varsity
  23          3             Rock & Roll
  24          5             Honour
  25          5             Arena
  26          6             E.T.
  27          6             boy
  28          6             alien
  29          6             phone home
  30          7             Home
  31          7             Alone
  32          7             robbers
  33          7             boy
```

...And so on. This table would be massive.

When a user visits the site, they can search for one word or a string of text. For example:

"*boy gets girl*"

What I would like to know how to do, or what it is called is to search the database for:

"*boy*", "*gets*", "*girl*", "*boy gets*", "*gets girl*", "*boy girl*", "*boy gets girl*".

Can this be done automatically? Is there a function for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is really split into two sections:

### Searching a database for arbitrary text

The name for this is "pattern matching", and in SQL it is implemented in a variety of ways:

- [The LIKE condition](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php)
- [Regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm)
- [MATCH-AGAINST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)

Of the three, the last is probably the most powerful. You can easily do what you want with:

```
SELECT * FROM table_tags WHERE MATCH(tag_text) AGAINST('boy gets girl');
```

The best part? **Rows are returned in order of relevancy**.

### Getting a movie based on a tag

I will assume because you are using this two-table model that you already know how to do joins, but just in case here's [a resource](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) for you. Once you have the tag ID, you can easily get the movie ID and from there the movie entity itself.

Comment: I was actually going to use three tables, the TOXI method I believe it is called. Which would you say is better. Also, as you can see I have genres too, so that may take a fourth table.

Comment: This returns a result "Notting Hill" when I search for "boy gets girl" but it doesn't return "Home Alone". It doesn't return a thing when I search for "boy"... Should it?

Comment: The advantage to TOXI is if you want to rename a tag. The disadvantage is that doing a search for multiple tags at once becomes harder since the tags are now normalized out to another table. Hard to say which is better, you know your DB best so you have to make the final choice :P

Comment: As for the weird results...it *should*. You could try it this way though: `SELECT * FROM table_tags WHERE MATCH(tag_text) AGAINST('+boy gets girl' IN BOOLEAN MODE);` That might work out better.

Comment: That doesn't produce anything other than "Notting Hill" again. I am still deciding on whether to go with three tables or just the two. I think three+ will be better as I can also use genres and other attributes to search movies by. Are you aware of any good tutorials?